# PHP Curl - Setting the URL to an in-site URL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

```
$ch = curl_init('localhost/beater');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); //timeout in seconds
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
     echo curl_errno($ch);
     //header('Location: error');
}
```

As the title says, instead of setting the domain every time, how can I just type the PHP file? (As it's on my domain).

If I set it to     `$ch = curl_init('beater');` or `$ch = curl_init('beater.php');` I just get "Error 3" which is a malformed URL

I hope you guys can help!

Comment: have you tried using a full url? (i mean with the protocol)

Comment: Yes, that works perfect and returns the JSON

Comment: The code with localhost works fine, but I want to just put something like "example.php" or in my case "beater.php"

Comment: So just to point out... localhost/beater works fine, but I want to get rid of the localhost part :)

Comment: why? I don't think relative urls will work, you can create a base url and append the rest using that though, but it terms of injecting a relative url, no it won't work